# Checking list of words before appending

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and wish to check a list for the presence of a word/string before appending. I want to write a script that reads a txt file, splits each individual line to generate a list of strings. For each word in each line I want to check if the word is already in the list and if not, I append it to the list. This is the part I seem to have a challenge at. Any ideas?

```
file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
object = open(file_name)
lst = list()
for i in object:
    lst = i.rstrip().split()
    if i in lst is True:
        continue
    else:
        lst = lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're not THAT far.. but you need to loop through the `split()` line. And maybe use some reasonable variable names...

```
file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
file_contents = open(file_name)
word_list = list()

for line in file_contents:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in word_list:
            word_list.append(word)

print(word_list)
```

As an optimization, you can avoid the inner `for` loop over `words` by using a `set()` instead of  `list()` because if you `add()` duplicates to a set they will be discarded.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved it! And much appreciate the comment.

Comment: No problem, but serious about the variable names.. avoid a lot of confusion later. And maybe you can accept my answer ;)